# Unix command to check .pl process is running

Tags: bash, unix, sh, cron

I wanna have a cronjob to check on my .pl program is it running before it runs.
I created a ms1000.sh program.

```
#!/bin/sh
# check MSSocket1000 process

ps -ef | grep -v grep | grep MSSocket1000.pl
# if not found - equals to 1, start it
if [ $? -eq 1 ]
then
perl /home/application/MSSocket1000.pl &
else
echo "MSSocket2000 is running..."
fi
```

Then in my crontab

```
55 09 * * *    /home/application/ms1000.sh
```

Tried it many times, but it doesn't seem to run the MSSocket1000.pl even when I checked through ps -ef|grep MSSocket1000.pl it is not running.

Wondering what I did wrongly.
Thanks.

Comment: Maby you need to use the full path to perl?

Comment: Are you sure every time `$?` is 1?. I think you can use the like this. `$? -gt 0 `. Just a suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to check against 0 and flip the if logic because the fail number is not always 1. It could be any number between 1 and 127.

```
if [ $? -eq 0 ]
then
echo "MSSocket2000 is running..."
else
perl /home/application/MSSocket1000.pl &
fi
```

It is better to use `pgrep` instead of `ps ... | grep`.

```
pgrep -f MSSocket1000.pl
```

It is better to use the command directly in the if condition.

```
if pgrep -f MSSocket1000.pl
then
echo "MSSocket2000 is running..."
else
perl /home/application/MSSocket1000.pl &
fi
```

And last but not least: it is good to indent your code.

```
if pgrep -f MSSocket1000.pl
then
  echo "MSSocket2000 is running..."
else
  perl /home/application/MSSocket1000.pl &
fi
```

Nitpick: use `printf` instead of `echo`.

```
  printf '%s\n' "MSSocket2000 is running..."
```